# VGG16 network. Same inputs, same weights, but different layer outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the feeling I'm stuck in something very trivial or maybe there are some details about VGG16 implementation that I don't know, but I am running the same network with the same inputs and same weights, yet I get different results when I inspect after the first convolutional layer. The key lies on running the global_variable_initializers. Which global variables are different such that the result of the network changes? In a regular convolution only the weights of the filters and the input are involved.

I've also checked the specific line where this layer is implemented in Keras and there is nothing odd nor difficult to understand:

```
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
```

This is a dummy code I wrote to check that the outputs are always different whereas the other parameters are the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

input_tensor = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1,32,32,3)))
model = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False, weights="imagenet")

layers = dict([(layer.name,layer.output) for layer in model.layers])
loss = tf.reduce_sum(layers["block1_conv1"])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
myloss = sess.run(loss)

# Always same input
print(np.sum(input_tensor.eval(session=sess)))
# Always same weights
print(np.sum(model.get_weights()[1]))
# Different value every time I run it
print(myloss)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
myloss = sess.run(loss)
print(myloss)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
myloss = sess.run(loss)
print(myloss)
```

Comment: Can you run `print(np.sum(model.get_weights()[1]))` after running `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` and see if the value is always same?

Comment: That value is always the same, even if I put it after global_variables_initializer. The thing is: the Variable corresponding to that weight is always changing. If I run tf.global_variables()[1].eval(session=sess) (corresponding to the weights of the first filter) is always different. I don't see how it does load the right imagenet weights in that case, because I get a different value everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we have to load a session using Keras. If we create one ourselves, the variables will be re-initialized.

Adding the following lines solved it:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
sess = K.get_session()
```